# TestRigor calling feature test

Tags: testrigor

Iam trying to test calling feature using testrigor and twilio

Below is my one line test :

call "+91797401288x" from "+9183196902x4" and verify it is ringing

What I did I  put 91797401288x on airplane mode to check test fails or not and test got passed,looks like there is some issue with tool ?? or am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You did everything correctly.  I was able to duplicate your issue and I created an issue ticket.  I will update here when I get a response from support.

Answer (score 0):

Sumit. The issue is that when testRigor calls, it can only perform the validation from the side that it is connected, which is the caller. If a phone is on airplane mode, from the caller's perspective, the phone may ring. The holder of the phone may not hear the ringing, but the ringback tone may still be sent to the caller depending on how the service provider and the particular phone communicate. Airplane mode is to prevent the phone's holder from being disturbed, but not to notify callers. You can test this by telling a friend of yours to turn their phone on airplane mode. You may need to try more than one friend or have your friend do the same to you. If you're calling, you may hear the ringback tone, but your friend would not hear the ringtone. That's what's happening on testRigor. From testRigor's perspective, it is ringing. The phone service provider would have to intervene in some way to notify the caller that the person they are calling is not available. Otherwise, testRigor has no way of knowing that the phone is on airplane mode.

-This answer is from direct feedback from testRigor engineers.